# How to select values between two number for two specific columns in a dataframe to plot as a 2D graph

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table like this.
I would like to plot X versus Y for values where 0.120<Y<0.210.
I could not find a starting place to begin that would return values for both X and Y in this range. Any help is much appreciated.

Table of X and Y values:

[image: Table of X and Y values]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow: What have you tried so far?  You get better responses to you questions if you have tried something specific to your problem. For starters take a look at Pandas and DataFrames.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of attaching a df as an image, please include a minimum reproducible code as part of your question. That way, we can copy and paste your data in our environment and help you solve this challenge.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) also applies to data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to copy and paste, but it didn't retain the formatting to look like the table. Also, I get the data from an Excel spreadsheet, and have not entered the data as a code. I think this would be close: data = {'X':  [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        'Y': [0.113,0.116,0.130,0.150,0.150,0.160,0.180,0.210,0.220,0.260,0.280]
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select parts (rows in your case) of a dataframe by a condition.

Have a look in the tutorial of pandas here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe

If you want to combine conditions put brackets () around each condition and connect them with an operator of your choice (in this case, I think the AND-operator & would be useful ;-) )

try something like this:

```
df[(df['Y'] > 0.12) & (df['Y'] < 0.21)].plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're having trouble finding a starting place, I would start by gathering your data and declaring variables to hold the x and y data.

```
y_vals = [0.113, 0.117, 0.123, 0.129, 0.130, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280]
x_vals = list(range(0, (len(y_vals)*10), 10))
```

Above, I initialized `y_vals` as a list that contains each value of y. For `x_vals`, I initialized it as a list that changes with the `y_vals`. For example, if you were to add more y values to `y_vals`, the `x_vals` will grow with it. `x_vals` utilizes the `range()` function to grow. You can read more about this function [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).

Now that we have our data, it's time to get into the meat of the problem.

```
def getPoints(x_vals, y_vals):
    points = []
    for i in range(0, len(y_vals) - 1):
        if ((y_vals[i] > 0.120) & (y_vals[i] < 0.140)):
            x = x_vals[i]
            y = y_vals[i]
            points.append([x, y])
    return points
```

Above, the method `getPoints()` is responsible for finding which values are in between 0.120 and 0.140, and compiles the points into a list. This function returns a list with nested lists that display the points as `[x, y]`.

---

**EDIT**: I had previously used the `arange()` function from the `numpy` library to check whether or not the numbers were within your boundaries. However, `floats` are not stored with 100% precision and will usually result in rounding due to the number of values a `float` can store. The much simpler approach is to simply just check if the number is between two numbers using comparison. For example:

```
if ((y_vals[i] > 0.120) & (y_vals[i] < 0.140))
```

---

Now, it's time to pass the data into the `getPoints()` function.

```
points = getPoints(x_vals, y_vals)
print(points)
```

The output is as follows:

```
[[20, 0.13], [30, 0.129], [40, 0.123]]
```

Full script:

```
def getPoints(x_vals, y_vals):
    points = []
    for i in range(0, len(y_vals) - 1):
        if ((y_vals[i] > 0.120) & (y_vals[i] < 0.140)):
            x = x_vals[i]
            y = y_vals[i]
            points.append([x, y])
    return points

y_vals = [0.113, 0.117, 0.123, 0.129, 0.130, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280]
x_vals = list(range(0, (len(y_vals)*10), 10))
points = getPoints(x_vals, y_vals)
print(points)
```

Hope it helps :) if you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: However, I have one question. I tried to modify to capture different data point, specifically between 0.100 to 0.240, but when I modify as follows it only returns []: 

if y_vals[i] in np.arange(0.100, 0.240, 0.001):

Comment: @Qwynes I apologize, I made a mistake in the code. Please see the edit that I made on the post where I cover a much simpler and more accurate approach to checking whether or not a number is in a certain range. Thanks for catching it!